# how to deserialize json in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have follow code which request from web

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.bigflix.com/BIGFlixApi.do?parameter=getProductType&partnerID=17&uniqueID=54325345435&timestamp=131286916367&digest=bf53cae8f364cfc1d796489d09e4cfd&nbsp&nbsp<br>");
HttpWebResponse responce = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream resstream = responce.GetResponseStream();
string tempString = null;
int count = 0;
do
{
    count = resstream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    if (count != 0)
    {
        tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);
        sb.Append(tempString);
    }
}
while (count > 0);
{
    Response.Write(sb.ToString() + "<br/><br/>");
    // string[] val = sb.ToString().Split('"');
}
```

After the run this code i will get this type of json

```
[
    { "id": 23, "name": "Video Clips" }, 
    { "id": 15, "name": "Deleted Scenes" }, 
    { "id": 9, "name": "Music Albums" }, 
    { "id": 7, "name": "Trailers" }, 
    { "id": 18, "name": "Short Films" }, 
    { "id": 21, "name": "Movie Clips" }, 
    { "id": 1, "name": "Movies " }, 
    { "id": 4, "name": "Plays" }, 
    { "id": 22, "name": "Scenes" }, 
    { "id": 2,  "name": "TV Show" }, 
    { "id": 5, "name": "Kids" }, 
    { "id": 16, "name": "Interviews" }, 
    { "id": 11, "name": "Film Songs" }, 
    { "id": 14, "name": "Making of Movie" }
]
```

Now i want deserialize this in asp.net(c#)
I tried to get a proper answer but didn't get.

Please advice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a class called FromFlix inseide App_Code like this

```
public class FromFlix
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now after the end of your while loop, do this.

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var response = ser.Deserialize<IList<FromFlix>>(sb.ToString());
```

The `response` is a `List<FromFlix>`, that is, a generic list of type FromFlix
This is how you should use it.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.bigflix.com/BIGFlixApi.do?parameter=getProductType&partnerID=17&uniqueID=54325345435&timestamp=131286916367&digest=bf53cae8f364cfc1d796489d09e4cfd&nbsp&nbsp<br>");
HttpWebResponse responce = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream resstream = responce.GetResponseStream();
string tempString = null;
int count = 0;
do
{
    count = resstream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    if (count != 0)
    {
        tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);
        sb.Append(tempString);
    }
}
while (count > 0);
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<FromFlix> response = ser.Deserialize<List<FromFlix>>(sb.ToString());
foreach (var item in response)
{
    Response.Write("ID: " + item.ID + "&" + "Name: " + item.Name + "<br/>");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sir it's give error Error 48 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Class1>' to 'string'

Comment: what did you do after this line?

Comment: after this i write  Response.Write(Responce);

Comment: Cannot convert type 'Class1' to 'string', 
'string' does not contain a definition for 'ID' and no extension method 'ID' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?),'string' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Error is coming

Comment: just copy paste my code and check pal. its working here. sigh... :)

Comment: thnx ur suggestion it's work fine thank u thank u your suggestion god bless u

Comment: naveen bro iam tried but it give me Error "Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array."

Comment: This is a comment on an old post, but you can simply getting the response stream by doing "using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream())) { json = sr.ReadToEnd(); }"

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) type to serialize and deserialize JSON data.

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var deserialized = serializer.Deserialize<TheTypeToWhichJSONWillMap>(myJson);
```

EDIT:

I'm not sure of what problems you're having with this, but the following is a working example with the JSON string you provide:

```
static string TheJson = "...";

public class TheType
{
    public int id { get; set;}
    public string name { get; set; }
}

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var deserialized = serializer.Deserialize<List<TheType>>(TheJson);
```

This leaves us with `deserialized` being an `List<TheType>` with 14 elements.

Comment: @Atul: What error does it give? Mr. Disappointment said he tested it and works.

Comment: hey any one help me please please