# JSON deserialize

Tags: c#, json

this is my JSON

```
[{"id":23,"name":"Video Clips"},{"id":15,"name":"Deleted Scenes"},{"id":9,"name":"Music Albums"},{"id":7,"name":"Trailers"},{"id":18,"name":"Short  Films"},{"id":21,"name":"Movie Clips"},{"id":1,"name":"Movies "},{"id":4,"name":"Plays"},{"id":22,"name":"Scenes"},{"id":2,"name":"TV  Show"},{"id":5,"name":"Kids"},{"id":16,"name":"Interviews"},{"id":11,"name":"Film Songs"},{"id":14,"name":"Making of Movie"}]
```

I have to deserialize it how should I do this? please help

Comment: Look at [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203770/how-to-deserialize-json-in-asp-net

Comment: how to deserialize this json in c sharp

Comment: [{"id":23,"name":"Video Clips"},{"id":15,"name":"Deleted Scenes"},{"id":9,"name":"Music Albums"},{"id":7,"name":"Trailers"},{"id":18,"name":"Short  Films"},{"id":21,"name":"Movie Clips"},{"id":1,"name":"Movies "},{"id":4,"name":"Plays"},{"id":22,"name":"Scenes"},{"id":2,"name":"TV  Show"},{"id":5,"name":"Kids"},{"id":16,"name":"Interviews"},{"id":11,"name":"Film Songs"},{"id":14,"name":"Making of Movie"}]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-dynamic-object/3806407

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON you have there represents an array of objects which look like Videos so first you will need to define a class to store each video like so:

```
public class Video
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

With this done you can make use of one of the many JSON libraries either built in or third party. For this example I have made use of [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/). Here is a link to the [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/).

Next you will need to make use of the DeserializeObject static generic method of the JsonConvert class like so, specifying the `List<Video>` type so that it knows the JSON to be de-serialized is a collection of Video objects:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

...

string json = "[{\"id\":23,\"name\":\"Video Clips\"},{\"id\":15,\"name\":\"Deleted Scenes\"},{\"id\":9,\"name\":\"Music Albums\"},{\"id\":7,\"name\":\"Trailers\"},{\"id\":18,\"name\":\"Short  Films\"},{\"id\":21,\"name\":\"Movie Clips\"},{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Movies \"},{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"Plays\"},{\"id\":22,\"name\":\"Scenes\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"TV  Show\"},{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"Kids\"},{\"id\":16,\"name\":\"Interviews\"},{\"id\":11,\"name\":\"Film Songs\"},{\"id\":14,\"name\":\"Making of Movie\"}]";

List<Video> videos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Video>>(json);
```

With this done you have a collection of Video objects to work with.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize the json using JavaScriptSerializer from the System.Web.Extensions dll which can be found in:

> C:\Program Files\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.Extensions.dll

After adding a reference to the DLL in the project add:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

And you will also need to set Target Framework to a non-Client Profile, for example:

> .NET Framework 4

[image]

Then use code like this one to deserialize the json:

```
var json = @"[{""id"":23,""name"":""Video Clips""},{""id"":15,""name"":""Deleted Scenes""},{""id"":9,""name"":""Music Albums""},{""id"":7,""name"":""Trailers""},{""id"":18,""name"":""Short  Films""},{""id"":21,""name"":""Movie Clips""},{""id"":1,""name"":""Movies ""},{""id"":4,""name"":""Plays""},{""id"":22,""name"":""Scenes""},{""id"":2,""name"":""TV  Show""},{""id"":5,""name"":""Kids""},{""id"":16,""name"":""Interviews""},{""id"":11,""name"":""Film Songs""},{""id"":14,""name"":""Making of Movie""}]";
var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var deserializedList = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<JsonType>>(json);
```